# Occupancy problem with limited capacity and two types of balls

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability

I am considering the following problem that I suspect to be standard.

One has a set of $N$ balls composed of a fraction $\alpha$ of red balls and $(1-\alpha)$ of black balls (we assume $\alpha N$ is an integer). The $N$ balls are thrown randomly into $N/K$ bins each with capacity $K$. If a ball falls into a bin which is aleady full, we throw it again until it falls into a bin which is not full (which is well-defined by assumption).

For each $k$, what is the distribution of the number of bins having each exactly $k$ red balls?

It would be great if any of you could give me references on this!

Thanks in advance & best!

Comment: Do you want the *exact* distribution? And in what order do you throw the balls?

Comment: I don't see what it adds to say that you are putting the balls into the bins one by one. You are selecting randomly from the ways to put $K$ into each, right?

Comment: The event that you put $k$ red balls into a particular set of bins is easy to quantify. This means you can use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Yes, I would like the exact distribution. @usul: I should have been more precised. At each step: I randomly draw a ball from the set of balls that have not been thrown yet and throw it randomly into a bin.

Comment: @Douglas Zare: yes, you are right, I am selecting randomly among all ways to put K balls into each bin. This is certainly a better description. Regarding your last point, I may have missed it but I realize there is an ambiguity in my statement: for each bin, consider the indicator function which takes value $1$ if the bin has exactly k red balls. I am interested in the distribution of the sum over all bins of these indicators, i.e., the number of bins having each $k$ red balls. (I edited the question)

Comment: Yes, you can compute the probability that there are exactly $s$ bins with exactly $k$ red balls using inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @Douglas Zare: Thanks, I see. Fixing a set of $s$ bin, if one can compute the probability that these $s$ bins have each exactly $k$ balls while each of the $n/K-s$ remaining bins do not have exactly $k$ balls, then one can use the inclusion-exclusion principle to complete the argument. So far, I am not seeing right away why the first probability is easy to compute, but I probably need to spend more time on it.

Comment: What is needed for inclusion-exclusion is that we can compute the probability that $s$ (and $s+1, s+2, ...$) particular bins have exactly $k$ red balls with no restriction on the others, not that we know that the other bins do not have exactly $k$.